# React native github action make apk

Tags: android, react-native, build, github-actions, apk

I have the following project [link](https://github.com/Angelk90/apkP), how do I make it via github action I can create an apk that you can easily install.

Can you give me a hand?

```yaml
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:

name: Build  
jobs:
  install-and-test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Install npm dependencies
        run: |
          npm install
  build-android:
    needs: install-and-test
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Install npm dependencies
        run: |
          npm install
      - name: Build Android Release
        run: |
          cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease
      - name: Upload Artifact
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v1
        with:
          name: app-release.apk
          path: android/app/build/outputs/apk/release/
```

Answer (score 2):

```
- uses: "marvinpinto/action-automatic-releases@latest"
        with:
          repo_token: "${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}"
          automatic_release_tag: "Production"
          prerelease: true
          title: "Development Build"
          files: |
            android/app/build/outputs/apk/release/app-release.apk
```

to automatically release

Answer (score 0):

You just have to execute Gradle as you are doing locally.

Take a look to this YAML sample:

```
name: Build Release APK

on:
  push:
    branch:
      - 'master'

jobs:
  Gradle:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: checkout code
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: setup jdk
      uses: actions/setup-java@v1
      with:
        java-version: 11
    - name: Make Gradle executable
      run: chmod +x ./android/gradlew
    - name: Build Release APK
      run: ./android/gradlew assembleRelease
```

Inspiration: https://github.com/marketplace/actions/build-android-release-apk-when-create-new-tag

Comment: ```Run chmod +x ./gradlew
chmod: cannot access './gradlew': No such file or directory
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.```

Comment: I changed the project link, I tried as you indicated but it doesn't work, it tells me: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DVm2x.png

Comment: Instead as I did here it seems to work: shorturl.at/joM18

But I can't release apk as auto release.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nyhzl.png

Comment: I can create Artifacts apk, but I don't know how to create an automatic release.